# Is the PDF rendering engine in QGIS atlas reports the same as for single page reports?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I’ve recently created a set of atlas maps in v3.6 that display contours. When I render a single page as PDF  it obeys the rule based display settings (for index and intermediate contours).

If I run the same example as an atlas, all the line weights appear the same. The ‘rendered view’ that shows in the print composer after the PDF has renders shows the correct line symbology.

So I’m wondering if the atlas uses the same PDF renderer, or if there is some other step I’m missing in the atlas logic

Comment: what rule-based settings are you using?